# ¿puedo tener distintos valores para una variable?

Tags: java

¿puedo tener distintos valores para una variable? algo asi:

```
marca = Dell o Toshiba o Lenovo
```

en java

Comment: Diría que lo que estás buscando es un tipo enumerado [`enum`](https://jarroba.com/enum-enumerados-en-java-con-ejemplos/)

Comment: No me queda claro qué es lo que quieres conseguir, puedes poner un ejemplo más concreto?

Comment: nesecito crear una clase que se llame Computador y tener el  atributo privado:
 marca: almacena Dell, o Toshiba, o Lenovo, etc.

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas es un tipo enumerado ([enum](https://jarroba.com/enum-enumerados-en-java-con-ejemplos/)). En el ejemplo que pones, puedes crear esta enumeración:

```
public enum Marca
{
    DELL,TOSHIBA,LENOVO
}
```

Y al crear tu variable usarías ese tipo:

```
Marca marcaOrdenador = Marca.DELL;
```

De esa manera, en `marcaOrdenador` solo podría almacenarse uno de los tres valores que has definido en tu tipo `Marca`.

Comment: yo te doy la derecha.. pero no se si esta preguntando esto, o no sabe directamente usar variables...

Answer (score 1):

Es posible, es un patrón de diseño algo antiguo.

Primeramente defines constantes para tus valores:

```
final static int DELL=1; //0001
final static int TOSHIBA=2; //0010
final static int LENOVO=4; //0100
final static int ALIENWARE=8; //1000
```

Luego para poderlas combinar usas operadores de bits.

por ejemplo:

```
int marca = ALIENWARE | DELL; // 1001
```

Nos indicaría una marca alienware y dell al mismo tiempo al ser una sub-marca.

Puedes usar el mismo truco para procesar los valores, por ejemplo:

```
public static String obtieneCategoria(int marcaComputadora)
{
  String descripcion;
  if(marcaComputadora & DELL)
  {
   descripcion+="Laptop";
  }
  if(marcaComputadora & ALIENWARE)
  {
   descripcion+=" Gamer";
  }
  return descripcion;
}
```

Y de esta manera obtener la categoría

> Laptop Gamer

al mandar llamar a la función como

```
System.out.println(obtieneCategoria(ALIENWARE | DELL));
```

Addendum: Se recomienda usar `EnumSet`s en vez de campos de bits, pero es menos verboso así. Si quieres más info al respecto te recomiendo leer este artículo en inglés http://eddmann.com/posts/using-bit-flags-and-enumsets-in-java/.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta abarca dos casos, los cuales son los siguientes:

1. Una variable no puede tener varios valores al mismo tiempo, osea en un determinado momento la variable tendrá un valor, después, durante la ejecución del programa este valor puede cambiar.

**Ejemplo:**

```
int valor = 0;
valor = 1;
valor = 2;
```

2. Sí te refieres a que sí la variable puede tener varios valores al mismo tiempo, la respuesta también es no, pero en este caso, sería un más bien, no del todo. Esto pues existe algo llamado [Vector](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-string-array-reference-java-5-for-loop-syntax), que es una estructura de datos capaz de guardar valores de un tipo de dato determinado en posiciones consecutivas. Es importante tener en cuenta que debes de definir el tamaño del vector (la cantidad de datos que va a poder guardar) y que el índice va a ser desde 0 hasta largo - 1.

**Ejemplo:**

```
String[] marcas = new String[3];
marcas[0] = "DELL";
marcas[1] = "HP";
marcas[2] = "MAC";

/*accedes al valor igualmente por el índice*/
String val = marcas[0]; //a la variable val se le asigna el valor que tenía marcas en la posición 1.
```

**Nota:**

Existe formas más eficientes de guardar múltiples valores en una variable, como los tipo [Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), listas enlazadas o cualquier otro tipo de colección de datos, pero creo que con el vector te sería suficiente para tu problema.

Answer (score -1):

una variable tiene un valor, lo que puedes hacer es almacenarlo en un arreglo y en las posiciones de este guardas los valores

```
public static void main(String [ ] args){
String [ ] variable = new String [3];
variable[0] = dell;
variable[1] = Toshiba;
variable[2] = lenovo;
```

}