# Como agregar varios objetos a un objeto?

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una clase llamada Libro en la cual los atributos son nombre id y un objeto de otra clase llamada autor. Mi pregunta es si es posible anadir varios autores a un solo objeto de la clase libro?

```
    package p;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Libro {
    private String nombre;
    private int id;
    private Autor autor;    

    public Autor getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    ArrayList<Libro> librolist = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Autor> autorlist = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Libro> getLibrolist() {
        return librolist;
    }

    public void setLibrolist(ArrayList<Libro> librolist) {
        this.librolist = librolist;
    }

    public ArrayList<Autor> getAutorlist() {
        return autorlist;
    }

    public void setAutorlist(ArrayList<Autor> autorlist) {
        this.autorlist = autorlist;
    }   
}
```

Clase Autor

```
package p;

public class Autor {
    private String nombre;
    private int id;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

Comment: En base al código que compartes no, no es posible, tendrías que modificar tu código.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario pero si me pudieras especificar un poco mas que es lo que esta mal te lo agradeceria

Comment: `private Autor autor;` esa variable solamente guarda un autor. para aceptar más deberías remplazarlo por una estructura de datos o en su defecto usar algún [truco](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115117/puedo-tener-distintos-valores-para-una-variable/115154#115154) para guardar dos valores en una misma variable.

Comment: Gracias Ruslan entonces tendria que utilizar un vector o algo parecido, en vez de un solo objeto en la parte de autor, no podria usar el arrayList?

Comment: Puede usar el arrayList para guardar autores, pero la properidad "autor" en la clase libro puede tener solamente un valór (como dició Ruslan.)  Por eso, no tiene sentido para tener "autor" y "autores" en la clase libro.

Comment: Tienes creado ArrayList<Autor> autorlist = new ArrayList<>(); es lo que necesitas para asignar varios autores a un libro. Los tendrías que ir añadiendo ahí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

de la mano a la solucion que dio @jachguate quisiera agregar otra opcion, el uso de [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). varargs nos permite definir un metodo que permite desde 1 hasta n paramentros del mismo tipo y creo que esta es una opcion exellente para esta pregunta por tanto la utilizando [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) seria:

```
public class Libro {
private String nombre;
private int id;
private Autor[] autores;    

//...

public void agregarAutores(Autor ...newAutores) {
    if (autores != null) {
       autores = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(autores),
           Arrays.stream(newAutores)).toArray(Autor[]::new);
    } else {
      autores = newAutores;
    }
}
//...
}
```

hay que destacar que [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) es similar a usar un array por tanto desde la perspetiva de `agregarAutores(Autor ...newAutores)` y `agregarAutores(Autor newAutores[])` es similar 
con respecto a los `Array.Stream()` eso esta explicado en [este link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-join-and-split) (pero basicamente esta linea de codigo combina 2 arrays en un solo array)

ahora como usar el metodo `agregarAutores(Autor ...newAutores)` es simplemente llamarlo con 1 o mas paramtros de tipo Autor:

`milibrox.agregarAutores(autor1,autor2);`

`milibrox.agregarAutores(autor3);`

`milibrox.agregarAutores(autor1,autor2,autor3);`

`milibrox.agregarAutores(autor1,autor2,...);`
etc...

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede, pero no das el detalle suficiente como para *producir* una solución, por lo que te daré dos alternativas para que valores la que más te conviene:

## Añadir un número definido de autores

Por ejemplo, hacer que pueda tener 3 autores, cada uno siendo un miembro de la clase, algo como:

```
public class Libro {
    private String nombre;
    private int id;
    private Autor autor1, autor2, autor3;    

    public Autor getAutor1() {
        return autor1;
    }

    public void setAutor1(Autor autor) {
        this.autor1 = autor;
    }

    public Autor getAutor2() {
        return autor2;
    }

    public void setAutor2(Autor autor) {
        this.autor2 = autor;
    }

    public Autor getAutor3() {
        return autor3;
    }

    public void setAutor3(Autor autor) {
        this.autor3 = autor;
    }
```

## Añadir un número variable de autores

En este caso, el autor puede ser cero, uno o varios. Nuevamente, habría varias maneras de implementar esto, por ejemplo, declarando como miembro de la clase un vector de autores y métodos para añadir nuevos autores. No tendría mucho sentido añadir un método para eliminar algún autor, pero podría hacerse también. En código, podría verse algo así:

```
public class Libro {
    private String nombre;
    private int id;
    private Autor[] autores;    

    public void agregarAutor(Autor autor) {
        if (autores != null) {
           Autor[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOf(autores, autores.length + 1);
           arr2[arr2.length - 1] = autor;
           autores = arr2;
        } else {
          autores = new Autor[1];
          autores[0] = autor;
        }
    }
```

Advertencia: El código puede tener errores, fue escrito acá mismo en el navegador y es para meros fines ilustrativos.