# Devolver 2 valores con un return desde un método a otro método no me funciona .Java

Tags: java

Buenas soy nuevo en esto y no se si me voy a explicar bien.

Estoy intentando que desde el método llamado:
`public static int[] drama()`

Me pueda llevar los dos valores llamados `nomPeliDr`, `MinPeliDr` al método
`public static int menu(int NOpcion)`

Y despues de eso que pueda sacar los valores individualmente para mostrarlos individualmente con un `System.out.println`. Después para llevarlos a un nuevo metodo que se llamara resumen y para poder dentro del metodo resumen por ejemplo sacar el valor de los MinPeliDr y sumarlos con un valor X (por ejemplo 50)

Adjunto todo el código:

```
package principal;

import java.util.Scanner;
    
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    public class Reto1 {
        
        static Scanner teclado; //Declaramos el teclado
        
        //Empezar Main
        
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            String Bienvenida=bienvenida(); // Nos lleva al metodo bienvenida
            
        }
        
        //Empezar metodo bienvenida     
        
        public static String bienvenida() 
        
        {
        
            String Temporizador=temporizador();
                
            return "";
            }
            
        //Empezar metodo temporizador
        
        public static String temporizador() 
        
        { 
                
            try {
                       
                System.out.println("Bienvenido a la aplicacion Cine Elorrieta");
                    
                Thread.sleep(3*1000);   //Ponemos a "Dormir" el programa durante los ms que queremos
                String Login=login();
                }
            
                catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                }
            
            return "";
            }
        
    
        //Empezar metodo Login
        
        public static String login()
        
        {
        
        teclado= new Scanner(System.in); //Iniciamos el teclado
        
        int NOpcion=0;
        
        System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre de Usuario:");
        String Usuario=teclado.nextLine();


        while (!Usuario.equals("Admin")) {  

        if(Usuario.equals("Admin")) {

        }else if(!Usuario.equals("Admin")) {
        System.out.println("Usuario Incorrecto. Vuelve a Introducir el Usuario");
        Usuario=teclado.nextLine();
        }
        
        }
        
        System.out.println("Introduce tu contraseña");
        String Pass=teclado.nextLine();


        while (!Pass.equals("12345")){

        if (Pass.equals("12345")) {
        System.out.println("Contraseña correcta");
        }else if(!Pass.equals("12345")) {
        System.out.println("Contraseña Incorrecta, Vuelve a introducir la contraseña");
        Pass=teclado.nextLine();
        }
        
        }

        System.out.println("Bienvenido/a administrador");

        int next=menu(NOpcion);

        return "";
        }
        
        
        //Empezar el metodo Elegir Opcion
        
        public static int menu(int NOpcion) 
                                            
        {
            
            teclado= new Scanner(System.in); //Iniciamos el teclado
            
            boolean salir = false;
            
            
            int opcion=0; //Guardaremos la opcion del usuario
            
            while (!salir) {
     
                System.out.println("Escribe un numero de las opciones para seleccionar la categoria");
                System.out.println("1. Drama");
                System.out.println("2. Comedia");
                System.out.println("3. Terror");
                System.out.println("4. Ciencia Ficcion");
                System.out.println("0. Salir");
                
                
                
                try {
     
                    opcion = teclado.nextInt();
     
                    switch (opcion) {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("Has seleccionado Drama");
                            int[] ListaDrama = drama();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Has seleccionado Comedia");
                            int Comedia=comedia();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Has seleccionado Terror");
                            int Terror=terror();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("Has seleccionado Ciencia Ficcion");
                            int Scifi=scifi();
                            break; 
                        case 0:
                            System.out.println("Has seleccionado Salir");
                            String Salir=salir();
                            salir = true;
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Solo números entre 0 y 4 por favor.");
                    }
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Debes insertar un número por favor.");
                    teclado.next();
                }    
                
                        }
            
            return opcion;  
        }   

        //Empezar Metodo Drama
        
        public static int[] drama()  
        
        {
        
        teclado=new Scanner(System.in); // 
            
        boolean error = false;  
        
        int nomPeliDr=0;
        
        
        int MinPeliDr=0;
        int MinPeli=110;//en proximas actualizaciones se sustituira el valor por la variable  que demos a las horas generales en el menu Genero
        
        int TiHo=8;
        int TiMin=60;   
        
        int Peli=0;
        int salir=0;
        
        do {
            
          do {
                
            System.out.println("Escoje entre una de las siguientes peliculas, introduciendo su numero:");
            
            
            String Drm1="Nº1. Handia: Duracion 1H 56min";
            String Drm2="Nº2. La Lista de Schindler: Duracion 3H 17min";
            String Drm3="Nº3. Cadena Perpetua: Duracion 2H 22 min";
            String Drm4="Nº4. Million Dollar Baby: Duracion 2H 13 min";
            
            
            System.out.println(Drm1);
            System.out.println(Drm2);
            System.out.println(Drm3);
            System.out.println(Drm4);
            System.out.println("0. Salir del Programa");
            
            try {
                
            error=false;
            Peli=teclado.nextInt();
            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error=true;
                System.out.println("Debes insertar un número por favor.");
                teclado.nextLine();
            }
            
            } while (error==true);
        
        if (Peli==1) {
              
                System.out.println("Seleccionada pelicula Handia");
                nomPeliDr=1;
                MinPeliDr=116;
                // System.out.println("Valores "+" Hora "+HoraPeliDr1+" Minutos "+MinPeliDr1);
          }
        else if (Peli==2) {
                    
                System.out.println("Seleccionada pelicula La Lista de Schindler");
                nomPeliDr=2;
                MinPeliDr=197;
                // System.out.println("Valores "+" Hora "+HoraPeliDr2+" Minutos "+MinPeliDr2);
          }
        else if (Peli==3) {
             
                System.out.println("Seleccionada pelicula Cadena Perpetua");
                nomPeliDr=3;
                MinPeliDr=142;
                // System.out.println("Valores "+" Hora "+HoraPeliDr3+" Minutos "+MinPeliDr3);
          } 
        else if (Peli==4) {
              
                System.out.println("Seleccionada pelicula Million Dollar Baby");
                nomPeliDr=4;
                MinPeliDr=133;
                // System.out.println("Valores "+" Hora "+HoraPeliDr4+" Minutos "+MinPeliDr4);
          }
                
        else if (Peli==0) {
                
                do {
                                
                System.out.println("¿Seguro que deseas salir?");
                System.out.println("1. Si");
                System.out.println("2. No");
                
                try {
                    
                    error=false;
                    salir=teclado.nextInt();    
                        
                    if (salir==1) {     
                            String Bienvenida=bienvenida();
                            
                    }
                    else if (salir==2) {
                    //      ArrayList<Integer> Drama=drama();

                    }
                    else if (salir<0 || (salir>2))  {
                        System.out.println("El valor introducido no es correcto, Por favor introduce un numero entre el 1 y el 2.");
                        error=true;
                        }
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    error=true;
                    System.out.println("Debes insertar un número entre el 1 y el 2.");
                    teclado.nextLine();
                }
                
                    } while (error==true);
            
            }   
            
        else if (Peli<0 || (Peli>4)) {
        System.out.println("El valor introducido no es correcto, Por favor introduce un numero entre el 1 y el 4.");    
        }
        
            } while (Peli<0 || (Peli>4));
        
        String Tiempo=formatearMinutosAHoraMinuto(MinPeliDr);
        System.out.println(formatearMinutosAHoraMinuto(MinPeliDr)+" minutos");
         
        int[] numeros;
        numeros = new int[] {nomPeliDr,MinPeliDr};
        
        
         return numeros;
            
        }
```

Pero no consigo sacarlos ni se muy bien como hacerlo con arrays o la forma apropiada para hacerlo. He intentado que me muestre los valores pero nada. La cosa que pudiese sacara los valores individualmente en el otro método que quiero llevarlo.

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El código se comparte siempre como texto, no como imagen. Lo otro, el fragmento que compartes no nos dice mucho sobre dónde quieres usar qué. Tienes un array de enteros con dos enteros que llegan como parámetro de la función, y te quieres llevar a otro método pero no sabemos cómo los quieres usar, de dónde salen, etc. Añade el código relevante (completo?) de los métodos, dejándonos ver si están en la misma clase, en paquetes diferentes, etc.

Comment: Recuerda que, para aclaraciones y para mejorar tu pregunta, puedes usar la opción [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/401792/edit) que aparece justo bajo tu pregunta y las etiquetas

Comment: Perdon es que soy nuevo, he cambiado un poco la publicacion a ver si ahora es mas especifico

Comment: Gracias por editar la pregunta! Ahora se entiende muchísimo más. Revisa si la respuesta que te dan te sirve. Efectivamente, estás devolviendo el array correctamente a la variable en el método `menu` y no sabemos si tienes lío pintando lo que retorna drama o en qué paso tienes problemas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿puedo tener distintos valores para una variable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115117/puedo-tener-distintos-valores-para-una-variable)

Comment: Tema solucionado =) Gracias a todos. Ya he marcado la respuesta que me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo de función que devuelve dos valores en un arreglo y luego son separados.

```
class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] valores = funcionQueDevuelveArregloConDosValores();
    
        // el primer valor esta en la posicion 0 del arreglo
        System.out.println(valores[0]);
        
        System.out.println(valores[1]);
      }
    
      public static funcionQueDevuelveArregloConDosValores(){
        // return básico
        return new int[]{1,2};
      }
    }
```

Comment: Voy a probar a ver si funciona ^^

Comment: Así si me funciona, únicamente tendría que cambiar un poco el codigo =) gracias