# Devolver varias variables de un método al main

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en el mundo de *Java* y estoy tratando de resolver algunos problemas de ejecución (más allá de que la lógica no sea la correcta por ahora).

El método "*decompose*" descompone en unidades, decenas y centenas:

```
public static void decompose(double number) {
    int units, tens, hundreds;          

    units = (int) number%10;
    number = number/10;
    tens =  (int) number%10;            
    number = number/10;
    hundreds = (int) number%10;
}
```

Quiero quedarme después con los valores para usarlos en el método *main*:

- units
- tens
- hundreds

He comprobado que haciendo `return units, tens, hundreds;` obtengo error.

¿Cómo puedo tomar esos valores y usarlos en el método main?

Indico el método *main* por si sirve de algo, aunque no creo que esté ahí mi error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double radio = 4;                              
    int height = 8, volume=0;

    volume = volume(radio, height);                     
    volume = decompose(volume);                        

    System.out.printf("Volume %.2f \n", volume);        

    System.out.println("Units: " + units);
    System.out.println("Tens: " + tens);
    System.out.println("Hundreds: " + hundreds);
}
```

Por favor díganme si hay más información que deba aportar.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Usando un metodo void no podras devolver valores , para ello deberas usar un metodo int o en tu caso de varios valores int[] .

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! o mucho mejor devolver una clase que contenga todos esos valores que vos qureres...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿puedo tener distintos valores para una variable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115117/puedo-tener-distintos-valores-para-una-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En java no puedes retornar mas de un valor y debes mencionar el tipo de valor que va a devolver el metodo cuando escribes Void esto quiere decir que no se retornara ningun valor, lo que puedes hacer es retornar un arreglo con los datos que quieres devolver por ejemplo:

```
public static int[] decompose(double number) {
 int units, tens, hundreds;          

 units = (int) number%10;
 number = number/10;
 tens =  (int) number%10;            
 number = number/10;
 hundreds = (int) number%10;

  return new int[]{units,tens,hundreds};
}
```

Comment: Luego en el método main debo hacer la llamada para tomar esos valores, entonces, verdad?

Comment: Claro, seria algo como int[] numbers = decompose(50);

Answer (score 4):

Para lo que quieres hacer tienes 2 opciones o bien puedes devolver una Lista o un Objeto que contenga los valores que tu deseas.

**Opción 1**

```
public static List<Integer> decompose(double number){
        int units, tens, hundreds;

        units = (int) number % 10;
        number = number/10;
        tens =  (int) number%10;
        number = number/10;
        hundreds = (int) number%10;

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(units);
        numbers.add(tens);
        numbers.add(hundreds);
        return numbers;
    }
```

Cuando llames al método simplemente recoge los valores en una lista y haz lo que quieras con estos, algo como lo siguiente

```
List<Integer> integers = decompose(40);
int units = integers.get(0);
int tens = integers.get(1);
int hundreds = integers.get(2);
```

A mi particularmente me gusta mas la segunda opción, primero que te creas un Objeto que va a ser tu modelo, algo como esto

**Opción 2**

```
public class MyNumber {

    private int units;
    private int tens;
    private int hundreds;

    public MyNumber(int units, int tens, int hundreds) {
        this.units = units;
        this.tens = tens;
        this.hundreds = hundreds;
    }

    public int getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits(int units) {
        this.units = units;
    }

    public int getTens() {
        return tens;
    }

    public void setTens(int tens) {
        this.tens = tens;
    }

    public int getHundreds() {
        return hundreds;
    }

    public void setHundreds(int hundreds) {
        this.hundreds = hundreds;
    }
}
```

Luego es tan sencillo como implementarlo en tu método de esta forma

```
public static MyNumber decompose(double number){
        int units, tens, hundreds;

        units = (int) number % 10;
        number = number/10;
        tens =  (int) number%10;
        number = number/10;
        hundreds = (int) number%10;

        MyNumber myNumber = new MyNumber(units, tens, hundreds);
        return myNumber;
    }
```

espero que te sea de utilidad.